# Grid column extending beyond border when using minmax function for width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CodePen at [CSS Grid with Border](https://codepen.io/james-hudson3010/pen/ZEWOwwZ) which illustrates this issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-properties">
  <div class="column-properties">Column A</div>
  <div class="column-properties">Column B</div>
  <div class="column-properties">Column C</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-properties {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content minmax( 400px, 1fr );
  column-gap: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 16px;
}

.column-properties {
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: xx-large;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

If the width of the window reduces to the point were the third column hits the 400px min width, the column extends beyond the border of the grid.

[image: overlap]

If I use:

```
grid-template-columns: max-content max-content 1fr;
```

the behavior works as expected.

I am not sure how to fix this or if this is considered a browser bug. The behavior is consistent across multiple browser engines.

Comment: I don't see any bug here. Min max is clearly stating the minimum and maximum ends of your width range for that column. 1fr is adjusting to the free space.

The real question is, what is your intended end result?

Comment: I want the border to surround all of the columns. When the width of the window shrinks to the point where the 400px min width of the third column takes over, the border no longer surrounds all of the columns. The border appears underneath the third column -- I do not want that.

Comment: Your `min-width` on Column C is working fine. It's just that with your current setup, your window essentially has to be at MINIMUM 741px wide to accommodate all 3 columns, gaps and margins. But because we can shrink the window below 741px, the 400px min width of your 3rd column becomes crushed and it bugs out. I suggest adding an overflow in the x direction so you can scroll to the right if you intend on keeping that 400px min width for Column C.

Comment: why not simply set a minimum screen width of 400px with overflow so that you have a scrollabr when goign below 400px. Alternativly for responsivness add @media breakpoints and define there what should happen if the screen with goes below 400px?

Comment: With the layout 400px is showing correctly. Set the last column to max-content too or just for with 1fr, repeat, auto-fill to get a similar effect

Comment: @SHenry Setting the last column to max-content will not work for my situation. It is not possible to use minmax in the way I am and still have the border surround grid?

Comment: Please help me understand the intended goal: My assumptions: 1) the 3rd column should never disappear in an overflow, or be forced to scroll. 2) If the screen gets smaller, you want the 3rd column to adapt and re-ajust properly, as when you did 1fr? 3) In a normal scenario, you want the column to have the min-width size of 400px but a free max size?

Comment: @Capagris the min width of the third column should be 400px. The border should always surround the grid. Beyond that, there isn't much -- you can assume that column C may contain some lengthy text, where A & B will not --- you can also assume that there will be more rows, but never more columns. I do not believe there is a better solution than the answer I provided below based on what kvncnls wrote above.

Comment: And what would be the desired behaviour when the total available width in your screen is smaller than 400px + whatever space your other two columns occupy? What should happen to each column then?

Comment: @Capagris below 400px, I would expect to have to scroll right to see the remainder of Column C. I think it might be better to scroll the entire window rather than just the grid, but I am not sure that is possible while also keeping the border surrounding the grid. The solution I provided below scrolls the grid.

Comment: then in that case, set the overflow properties for the body or whatever wrapping element you're thinking of that goes before your grid.

Comment: @Capagris I tried that...couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220048/discussion-between-capagris-and-james-hudson).

Comment: updated the codepen

Answer (score 0):

let me know if this work for you or not.

```
display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
```

or

```
display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @kvncnis, this appears to be the solution:

```
.grid-properties {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content minmax( 400px, 1fr );
  column-gap: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

(if anyone can add to or provide more accurate details, I would be interested)

What is going on is that overflow behavior is taking over. By adding `overflow-x: scroll`, the browser is told the correct thing to do when the overflow occurs.